# How to hide the Google Chrome status bar on a website

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps

I have noticed the movement towards Progressive Web Apps (PWAs), so I'm trying to learn what they're all about.

In most PWA's, I see that the browser chrome is hidden (the URL bar, the back button, home button, search fields, etc.). I'm trying to figure out how this is done.

I'm trying to build a new PWA from scratch and have, tried this so far:

```js
var hideNav = 'location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes';

window.open('test.html', 'null', hideNav);
```

That is what I wrote in my test.html file. This works when I view the app on Desktop, but it doesn't work on Mobile.

(I recently migrated from an android developer to a web developer, so I don't know languages like JavaScript and PHP as well as Java.)

Comment: And this did not work?

Comment: Love your nickname btw

Comment: It worked on Desktop but not on mobile. I thought i mentioned that. Sorry.

Comment: Oh yeah, this will surely not work on mobile phones.  PWA on mobile phones only hide the scrollbar when the user adds it to the homescreen. So it behaves like a native app (has its own window, fullscreen, etc)

Comment: Thanks for the compliment on my nickname.
Tho how do i set it up to be full screen on mobile? I want it to behave like a normal java application because when i go on smaller screens (320px width) and on landscape, it doesnt fit everything on the screen, there is a ton of scrolling etc. Any ideas on how i should fix that?

Comment: When i was making it, it looked great in the Chrome responsive view in developer's setting. But when i ran it on my old nokia phone, when the status bar was showing there was barely any space to scroll...

Answer (score 2):

You can do so through the **Web App Manifest**. Here a really good [article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/) from the Google Developers site about it.

The Web App Manifest allows developers to control how their apps appear when they are added to the homescreen (another PWA feature). In your specific need, you'd be looking to customize the display type from the Web App Manifest. You can read more about it in the linked article.